# SwiftUI Picker not displaying Options

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't seem to find any information on this, anywhere. So I'm learning SwiftUI, and I'm trying to add a `Picker` to a `Form`, but the picker won't display the available options when tapped. I don't really know what else to tell you guys so could someone take a look and help me fix this? thanks :)

```
//Outside the body code
    @State var contacts: [String] = [""]
    @State var types: [Type] = [.mobile]
//Inside the body code and inside a Form{}
    Section(header: Text("Contact")){
            ForEach(0..<types.count, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack{
                    Picker(selection: $types[i], label: Text(""), content: {
                        Text("Mobile").tag(Type.mobile)
                        Text("Land Line").tag(Type.landline)
                        Text("Email").tag(Type.email)
                    }).pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: 80.0)
                    TextField("Insert Detail", text: $contacts[i])
                }
            }
            Button("Add Another") {
                types.append(.mobile)
                contacts.append("")
            }
```

Comment: `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!. This is the message printed on console when I tested your code, and it’s clear what went wrong.

Comment: @TusharSharma what should the explicit Id look like?

Comment: `ForEach(0..<types.count, id:\.self)` and make sure each enum case in unique in types array.

Comment: correction, I remember this now, I had this, and changed to what I have n my question because I needed the index of the loop. Is there a way to get the index `i` while specifying the ID explicitly?

Comment: I suspect I now need to ask a new question to work out how to do what I need, If you wanna post your answer I'll accept it 4 ya :) @TusharSharma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently managed to resolve this problem.

Picker needs to be wrapped in a NavigationView before it will work in a form.

I was able to simply add a NavigationView to the top of my view and put the form inside it, and now the picker works perfectly.

```
var body: some View{
    NavigationView{
        Form{
            ....
            Picker()
            ....    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments-:

> ForEach(*:content:) should only be used for constant data. Instead
> conform data to Identifiable or use ForEach(*:id:content:) and provide
> an explicit id!.

If you want to update your `types` array, change `forEach` line to  `ForEach(0..<types.count, id:\.self)`, and make sure your enum values are unique in array.

Comment: sorry, I just realised this didn't actually fix the problem -_-  it got my button working, but not my Picker (which was the main point of the question lol)

Comment: what isn’t working in picker? It’s working fine for me.

Comment: it will show me "Mobile", the rawValue for the .mobile already in the types array, but when I tap on the picker to change the selection nothing happens

Comment: Nothing in the log for me either, Not even sure how to debug this

Comment: seems like a bug with forms in iOS 14.5

Comment: I just for there myself, picker works fine outside of the Form, all of it works fine outside of the form -_- ..... might have to restructure my code now to use List instead of Form